# Design a mini script language

Tags: language-design

my project this year is to develop a text mining tool (with new features)
so we need  a mini script language in this tool to add annotation to texts
this language should be simple and like lisp grammars (left and right side) .
what i need is how to design this language ,i know how to constract the compiler , 
but how to write language grammars ? , and i want to use some mini open source language or any language bnf
please advice me and if there is a language i can use and customize to meet my needs ?

**EDIT :** if anybody can give a link for grammar (bnf) for lisp or any language like it

many thanks

Comment: if you want `simple and like lisp` why you don't use lisp or scheme.

Comment: Wouldn't a scripting language imply an interpreter, and exclude a compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider us this
http://www.antlr.org/
to design your language.

Comment: thanks but we antlr to write the compiler not to write language rules !

Comment: Sorry I was misleaded by the fact you were asking about "how to write language grammars"... anyway if .NET is your environment you can try IronPython

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would recommend just using Lua.  If you use their interpreter, which is designed to be easily embedded in other programs, it will save you the time of designing, implementing, and testing your own language.

Otherewise, you may be able to re-use the Lua parser code to parse your own Lua-like language.